# Authorization doesn't work after deployment on azure

Tags: authentication, azure, oauth, asp.net-web-api, owin

Im building a single page app with angularJS and WebApi 2.
Im using OAuth bearer token authentication with Owin middleware.
While everything works on the localhost,after deployment to Azure I get 401 when trying to access my web api.

Is there additional config on azure?
What should i do?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

How did you do your deployment to Azure? Deploying to Azure requires a change in the apps' return URI, to match the new location. If you create a new entry for the app, instead of modifying the existing one with the new return URI, you will get a new clientID. Your backend API verifies incoming tokens based on the clientID value in its web.config: if the clietnID value changes and you don't update it in the web.config before deploying to azure, the token check will fail.

Comment: In VS 2013 express right click on the project and publish.Can you please explain the steps for resolving this?P.s I dont have clientId in my current web.config.Where i can get it?

Comment: See "how to deploy to azure" from https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-DotNet/blob/master/README.md. Remember that in this case your web api the audience should be set to the clientid of your app, as explained in https://github.com/AzureADSamples/SinglePageApp-AngularJS-DotNet

Comment: i dont want to use AD.Is it a must?

Comment: It's not a must, but that's what samples are based on. You can abstract away the elements that don't fit your scenario, but of course that makes reading the sample harder.

Comment: I just want my OAuth to work.why is it so complicated?

Comment: I agree this should not be very complicated. There is one single value that is used for deciding whether your incoming token is valid. You only need to get that one value right, and it seems that you do on localhost. Unfortunately not knowing how your app is configured, it is kind of hard to give advice. If you would be working on AAD I would be able to narrow things down further, but if you are using custom stuff I have nothing to work on.

Comment: what kind of config would help you to help me?So I should work with Azure Active Directory?